# Вывод значений графика циклом или передача параметров PHP в JavaScript

Tags: php, циклы, javascript

Хай всем.

Есть функция вывода графика, которая выполняет запрос в БД и возвращает 2 параметра.
После эти параметры передаются в цикл, формирующий javascript.

Все работает, но есть одна проблема. При срабатывания цикла добавляется еще одно совсем ненужное значение.

Возможно ли изменить цикл так, чтобы этого значения не добавлялось и при этом он работал.

[image: graph]

```
var chartData = [{
<?php
      while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
?>
          dep_name: "<?=$row["dep_name"]?>",
          value: <?=$row["COUNT(u_id)"]?>
          },{
<?php
      }
?>
}];
```

**UPD**. Если возможно, подскажите, как это реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну можно так:

Перед тем как формировать график:

```
delete chartData[chartData.length - 1];
```

Вообще вот так делайте:

```
var chartData = [
<?php
      while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
?>        {
          dep_name: "<?=$row["dep_name"]?>",
          value: <?=$row["COUNT(u_id)"]?>
          },
<?php
      }
?>
];
```

Comment: Спасибо,второй вариант,то что надо.(эх все из-за незнания js..надо будет выучить)